# Function prototyping in C

Tags: c, clang, function-prototypes

Today Clang, trying to compile a program, gave me kinda an strange message. I'm not really experienced with C, so I might be doing something wrong, but the code that I actually tried is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(a,b);

int main ()
{
    printf(sum(1,2));
    return 0;
}

int sum (int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

As you have probably noticed, when declaring the function 'sum', I'm not including the param. type, so an error is expected, but the actual message Clang gives me is this:

```
ind.c:4:9: error: a parameter list without types is only allowed in a function definition
int sum(a,b);
        ^
ind.c:12:5: error: redefinition of 'sum' as different kind of symbol
int sum (int a, int b)
    ^
ind.c:4:5: note: previous definition is here
int sum(a,b);
    ^
2 errors generated.
```

What does Clang mean when it says it is only allowed in function definitions? Isn't `int sum(a,b);` a function definition?

Comment: Additionally, you're going to have some problems when you try to `printf` the return value of `sum(1,2)`.  Try `printf("%d", sum(1,2))` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `int sum(a, b);` is, or rather looks like, a function *declaration*, not a *definition*.

A function declaration provides enough information for the compiler to generate calls to the function.  A definition provides a declaration and, in addition, defines the code that will be executed when the function is called (the stuff between `{` and `}`).

A function declaration (that's not part of a definition) may include the types of the parameters, or the types and their names, but not just their names.  (If it includes the types, it's a *prototype*.)

An *old-style* function definition can have just the names of the parameters, for example:

```
int sum(a, b)
int a;
int b;
{
    return a + b;
}
```

But old-style definitions and declarations are obsolescent, and are best avoided.  An old-style declaration doesn't specify the number of type(s) of the parameters, so the compiler can't verify the correctness of calls.

Your declaration *could* look like this:

```
int sum();
```

but it *should* look like this:

```
int sum(int a, int b);
```

or even this:

```
int sum(int, int);
```

Oh, and `int main ()` is better written as `int main(void)`.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, Keith. Very clear and concise. You deserve this as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

`int sum();` is a function *declaration*. It names the function but doesn't tell the compiler what it does. Telling the compiler what it does is *defining* the function, so that's what it means. If rather than the semicolon you had curly brackets with statements in, you'd have a function definition.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer, Graham. I got it. Thanks again.